# Topological modular forms on cuspidal elliptic curves

Tags: homotopy-theory, elliptic-curves

If you take the moduli stack of smooth elliptic curves, there is a sheaf of $E_{\infty}$-rings on it whose global sections are isomorphic to $TMF$. This sheaf extends to the moduli stack of smooth/nodal elliptic curves (and global sections are isomorphic to $Tmf$). In the TMF book, they say that there is probably no extension of our sheaf to the moduli stack of smooth/nodal/cuspidal elliptic curves. Is this true? Has it been rigorously written down somewhere?

Comment: There are lots of issues with doing something like this, but the first is even formulating a statement: this "extra compactified" stack is not a Deligne-Mumford stack, so there is some issue even specifying what 'site' you'd want to have a sheaf on. (The easiest site to define would be something like an fppf or lisse-etale sort of thing, but I think it's possible to prove that this can't work using standard counterexamples like the nonexistence of an E_infty version of p-adic K-theory with a pth root of unity adjoined.)